# input output of point on the pline a(x , y)

Tags: c

how to use scanf without skeep the  line
or ho to enter a coordonnées of points A(x;y) x,y are an input valeur

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your description of your problem wasn't as good as I hoped it to be, look to improve that in the future please.
Nevertheless, I understand your question in this way:

`How to read x and y Coordinates of a 2-Dimensional Point without leaving the newline Character in the stdin buffer using scanf`

You can achieve this by using this piece of code

```
int x, y;
scanf("%d %d\n", &x, &y);
```

What it does is, it reads one decimal number, then a space, then another decimal number and after this a newline character.
The two decimal numbers are put into x and y, because you passed pointer to them.